# Correct way of selecting the jth row while using summarise after group_by

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

My query is: May I use summarise after group_by like this:

```
mydataset %>% 
arrange(grouping_variable,ordering_variable) %>%
 group_by(grouping_variable) %>% summarise(answer = another_variable[j])
```

I expect to see the jth ranked row in each group when I do the above.

I think the above is ***correct*** but ***not mentioned*** in the documentation.

I ran the following experiment to determine this.

Here is the whole data set:

```
> mtcars %>% arrange(cyl,mpg) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% as.data.frame
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1  21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
2  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
5  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
6  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
7  27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
8  30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
9  30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
10 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
11 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
12 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
13 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
14 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
15 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
16 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
17 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
18 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
19 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
20 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
21 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
22 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
23 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
24 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
25 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
26 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
27 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
28 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
29 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
30 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
31 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
32 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
```

Here is the first row (j=1) in each group:

```
> mtcars %>% arrange(cyl,mpg) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(answer =  mpg[1])
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    cyl answer
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     4   21.4
2     6   17.8
3     8   10.4
```

Here is the second row in each group (j=2):

```
> mtcars %>% arrange(cyl,mpg) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(answer =  mpg[2])
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    cyl answer
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     4   21.5
2     6   18.1
3     8   10.4
>
```

On [the help](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html) page, it says that way to do this is as follows:

```
> mtcars %>% arrange(cyl,mpg) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(answer = first(mpg))
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    cyl answer
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     4   21.4
2     6   17.8
3     8   10.4
> 

> mtcars %>% arrange(cyl,mpg) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(answer = nth(mpg,2))
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    cyl answer
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     4   21.5
2     6   18.1
3     8   10.4
>
```

I don't remember which website I read this on. Since it was not mentioned on help page that I why I am asking here.

Comment: The `summarise()` documentation *does* mention `nth()` under ['Useful Functions'](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html#useful-functions).

Comment: This question is not really about code but about documentation and how to ask it. You should probably think more about what exactly you're trying to ask and try to reformulate your question - there are a lot of unnecessary details.

Comment: the `first` and `nth` functions are mentioned on the help page. My query is : can we use summarise by indexing a variable after doing a group_by ? There is ***no*** example on the help page which does that. Hence my query.

Comment: Could you edit your question to give an example of what you're trying to achieve (but are currently unable to)? I'm possibly misunderstanding but it seems like you've already done what you're describing in your question.